# "This port will be preserved and left unconnected if it belongs to a top-level block...." in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, hdl

I am getting the following warning in Xilinx when I synthesize my code of a 4-bit multiplier:
**"This port will be preserved and left unconnected if it belongs to a top-level block or it belongs to a sub-block and the hierarchy of this sub-block is preserved."** I dont see any problem in my code that can cause this warning.

The code is as follows:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_bit.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity mult4X4 is
Port ( Clk : in  bit;
       St : in  bit;
       Mplier : in  unsigned (3 downto 0);
       Mcand : in  unsigned (3 downto 0);
          Result : out unsigned (7 downto 0);
       Done : out  bit);
end mult4X4;

architecture behave1 of mult4X4 is
signal State : integer range 0 to 9;
signal ACC : unsigned (8 downto 0);
alias M : bit is ACC(0);

begin
process(Clk)
begin
    if Clk'event and Clk = '1' then
        case State is
            when 0 =>
                if St = '1' then
                    ACC(8 downto 4) <= "00000";
                    ACC(3 downto 0) <= Mplier;
                    State <= 1;
                end if;
            when 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 =>
                if M = '1' then
                    ACC(7 downto 4) <= ACC(7 downto 4) + Mcand;
                    ACC(8 downto 0) <= '0' & ACC(8 downto 1);
                    State <= State + 1;
                else
                    ACC <= '0' & ACC(8 downto 1);
                    State <= State + 2;
                end if;
            when 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 =>
                ACC <= '0' & ACC(8 downto 1);
                State <= State + 1;
            when 9 =>
                Done <= '1';
                State <= 0;
                Result <= ACC(7 downto 0);
        end case;
    end if;
end process;
--Done <= '1' when State = 9 else '0';
--Result <= ACC(7 downto 0);
end behave1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simulating it.

Without simulating it myself I'd guess you're getting all '0's on Result.

These:

```
                ACC(7 downto 4) <= ACC(7 downto 4) + Mcand;
                ACC(8 downto 0) <= '0' & ACC(8 downto 1);
```

Will result in the Multiplicand's influence being eradicated.  There is no time between assignments to ACC. See IEEE Std 1076-1993 8.4.1 Updating a projected output waveform (-2008 10.5.2.2 Executing a simple assignment statement), the paragraph starting "The sequence of transactions is ..." and the following narrative. The first assignment's scheduled transaction for the affected bits of ACC (7 downto 4) are deleted as old transactions. For composite types (and ACC is) it happens on an element by element basis.

And it looks like it will get all '0's because of the second assignment statement.

Also from simply reading your state machine the second of those two ACC assignments should simply be deleted in States 1 | 3 | 5 | 7?

**Addendum**

After Yann Verneir pointed out another error with `Done` never being assigned '0' I figured I'd demonstrate the effects of the two assignment statements to `ACC` in States 1 | 3 | 5 | 7.

A simple testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_bit.all;

entity mult4x4_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of mult4x4_tb is
    signal clk:             bit;
    signal start:           bit;
    signal multiplier:      unsigned (3 downto 0) := X"2";
    signal multiplicand:    unsigned (3 downto 0) := X"4";
    signal result:          unsigned (7 downto 0);
    signal done:            bit;

begin

DUT:
    entity work. mult4x4
        port map (
            Clk => clk,
            St  => start,
            Mplier => multiplier,
            Mcand => multiplicand,
            Result => result,
            Done => done
        );

CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if Now > 300 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;

STIM:
    process 
    begin
        wait for 29 ns;
        start <= '1';
        wait for 20 ns;
        start <= '0';
        wait;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

gives:

[image: mult4x4 testbench]

You can see that when using package numeric_bit instead of packages std_logic_1164 and numeric_std we never see anything but all '0's on `Result`.

Yann's assignment to '1' only on `Done` can be cured by:

```
    case State is
        when 0 =>
            if St = '1' then
                ACC(8 downto 4) <= "00000";
                ACC(3 downto 0) <= Mplier;
                State <= 1;
                Done <= '0';
            end if;
```

Removing the second signal assignment to `ACC` in the sequential statements for cases `1 | 3 | 5 | 7` gives an answer that look's right for 2 x 4:

[image: mult4x4_tb fixed]

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the warning is speaking of a port. I expect the line just above would tell you precisely which port, but it's easy enough to derive.

The port will be left unconnected. That means it must have no effect. The easiest way to have no effect is to be unused. All of the ports are accounted for in the process, so we look for other ways they aren't meaningful. Done looks like a prime candidate; it is set to 1 when the state machine finishes, but there's no reset; this means it goes from undefined to high, and stays. The optimizer could replace that with just a high output. A reasonable place to reset it would be at the start condition.

In general the code has no reset, which may be fine if the state machine can recover from any state, but won't simulate properly. Don't be sure it will reset just because of the range of the State signal; having ten values, it would require 4 bits to store causing 6 invisible states with undefined behaviour; or it could well be encoded to one hot, which if not reset could cause multiple states to appear simultaneously.